Running vsftpd in Docker (Swarm)
I want to use a vsftp-Server in my Docker Swarm but having some network issues. I have the following compose-file:
services:
  vsftpd:
    container_name: vsftpd
    image: million12/vsftpd
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - /whatever:/var/ftp/:ro
    environment:
    - ANONYMOUS_ACCESS=true
    - LOG_STDOUT=true
    - CUSTOM_PASSIVE_ADDRESS="<myexternalswarmadress>"
    ports:
    - 20-21:20-21
    - 21100-21110:21100-21110
      #network_mode: "host"

If i run this compose file with docker compose and network mode "host" then i can easily connect to it.
If i run it without network mode "host" i have the following output:
Status: Angemeldet
Status: Empfange Verzeichnisinhalt...
Befehl: PWD
Antwort:    257 "/" is the current directory
Befehl: TYPE I
Antwort:    200 Switching to Binary mode.
Befehl: PASV
Antwort:    500 OOPS: invalid pasv_address
Befehl: PORT 10,10,10,102,10,187
Fehler: Verbindung vom Server geschlossen

I can see the login in the output of the vsftp-Server:
vsftpd  | [VSFTPD 16:46:41] VSFTPD daemon starting
vsftpd  | Tue Nov 19 16:46:45 2024 [pid 33] CONNECT: Client "<myclientip>"
vsftpd  | Tue Nov 19 16:46:45 2024 [pid 32] [ftp] OK LOGIN: Client "<myclientip>", anon password "anonymous@example.com"

I have the same results if i run it on swarm.
It seems like im having issues with the "passive ports" and the docker network. Unfortunately there is no "network_mode: host" in swarm (even if i pin the service to a host)
Is there a possibility to run vsftpd in passive Mode in Swarm like Compose with Network-Mode ? Or are there other ways to bring up a working ftp-Server in Swarm?
